# Filter json results

Tags: javascript, json, filter, endpoint

I've created a JS file that fetches all parent / child activities from API endpoint. The output of the activities is shown in the tree-structure (parent > child + child, parent > child > child, ...).

I've also added a search input field that automatically filters the shown activities. But something very odd is occurring. When I try to type, nothing appears in the input field. It looks like character is automatically removed in the input field and the focus from the field is lost. I've did a console log from the input, and I see each character seperately.

This is my filter function:

```
filterActivities(searchTerm) {
    if (!searchTerm) {
      this.filteredData = this.data.result;
    } else {
      this.filteredData = this.data.result.filter((item) => {
        const { activityId, description } = item;
        const lowerCasedActivityId = activityId.toString().toLowerCase();
        const lowerCasedDescription = description.toLowerCase();
        return (
          lowerCasedActivityId.includes(searchTerm) ||
          lowerCasedDescription.includes(searchTerm)
        );
      });
    }
    this.render();
  }
```

And here is the part where I attach it to the input field:

```
const searchInput = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#search-input');
    searchInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
      const searchTerm = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();
      this.filterActivities(searchTerm);
      console.log(searchTerm);
    });
```

The full JS code can be found here:
https://codepen.io/dennisperremans/pen/ZEmLZEg